# amcharts - How to bold text while hovering over it?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, treemap, amcharts4

I need that while hovering over a square in TreeMap the text is bolded.
I was only able to do darken into a square.

This is darken's code:

```
const level1 = chart.seriesTemplates.create("0");
let level1_column = level1.columns.template;
const level1_bullet = level1.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());


// create hover state
const hoverState1 = level1_column.states.create("hover");
// darken
hoverState1.adapter.add("fill", (fill) => {
    if (fill instanceof am4core.Color) {

        return am4core.color(am4core.colors.brighten(fill.rgb, -0.3));
    }
    return fill;
})
```

**I want while hovering that the text below is bolded:**

```
level1_bullet.label.text =  "{name}";
```

Comment: Does something like this work? `level1_bullet.label.text =  "[bold]{name}[/]";`

Comment: I only need when I hover over the square so that the text is bolded. In your answer the text is always bolded